# GPG error KEYEXPIRED when using sudo apt-get update (Ubuntu 15.04)

Tags: apt, gnupg

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1435908620 KEYEXPIRED 1435908620 KEYEXPIRED 1435908620 The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 63F7D4AFF6D61D45
trevor@trevor-Latitude-D620:~$
```

Comment: follow below link
http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey

Comment: mark as a correct answer and vote it please

Comment: @khanthegeek. Please also flag duplicates as duplicates in the future...  **;-)**